# Any other plugins or way of implementing something like jScrollPane

Tags: jquery

I have just started to look into how I can implement a scroll pane in a window. I had a suggestion to use jScrollPane. This looks good but I'm also wondering if there are other solutions. For example any solution using jQuery UI.

Has anyone come across anything similar to jScrollPane.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I like Tiny Scrollbar.

http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/

**Good thing:** It is clean, easy to implement and work with modal windows (jScrollPane does not work for me with my UI windows, but I am using many other component wich can cause a problem)

**Dark Side:** You need to modify your html to the structure they suggest. if not the component is not going to work :(

I hope it works for you!